# Filtering a column of lists of strings in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'sym':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],'event':[['1','2', '3'], ['1'], ['2', '3'],['2']]} )
```

df

> 

```
    sym event
0   A   [1, 2, 3]
1   B   [1]
2   C   [2, 3]
3   D   [2]
```

Event column is made up of lists of strings.  I am trying to filter the event column for any rows that contain '3' so I am looking for index 0 and 2.

I know to use

```
["3" in df.event[0]]
```

for each row and I think a lambda function would push me over the finish line.

Comment: `df[df.event.astype(str).str.contains('3')]`? Or whats your desired output?

Comment: Thats it.  Perfect.  thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
print(df[df.event.astype(str).str.contains(r'\b3\b')])



sym      event
0   A  [1, 2, 3]
2   C     [2, 3]
```

Comment: this will filter the '33' as well ~

Comment: Thanks, edited to ensure only 3 is picked

Answer (score 3):

[Series.explode to split list-like values to rows](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas.DataFrame.explode)

use `explode` to turn a list to row:

```
'3' in df['event'].explode().values
```

to find which row contains '3', use index:

```
idx = df['event'].explode() == '3'
df.loc[idx[idx].index]
```

Comment: thanks. so how would I filter the df rows rows where df['event'] contains "3"?

Comment: you can use the row's index. as `explode` keep the row's origin index.

Comment: you can also do: `df['event'].explode().eq('3').any(level=0)` with explode . Adding an alternative :)

Answer (score 2):

Let us try

```
out = df[pd.DataFrame(df.event.tolist()).isin(['3']).any(1).values]
Out[78]: 
  sym      event
0   A  [1, 2, 3]
2   C     [2, 3]
```